# Porque “órgão” leva dois acentos?

Tags: ortografia, linguística, sinais-gráficos

Aprendi que em português só a sílaba tónica leva acento.

Então como é que *órgão* pode levar dois acentos?

Porque é que não se escreve **orgão* ou **órgam*?

Comment: A pergunta está escrita em pt-PT, por exemplo "tónica". Em pt-PT o título fica errado com "por que" - ficaria a significar "por qual órgão leva dois acentos".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Órgão **não tem** dois acentos. O *til* (**~**) não é um acento e sim um **sinal** que representa que este fonema (**a**) é nasalizado.

- **E como é que til não é acento?**

Acentos só podem recair sobre a sílaba tônica da palavra. Como já dito, til não é acento, é um sinal auxiliar de **nasalização**. Tanto que:

1. Ele pode estar sobre uma sílaba átona. Ex.: órgão, sótão, órfão;
2. Pode aparecer várias vezes numa mesma palavra. Ex.: fogãozão.
3. Mesmo que a sílaba tônica seja trocada para se acrescentar um sufixo na palavra, o til não muda. Ex.: irmão - irmãozinho.

Todos os comportamentos supracitados não podem ser seguidos por acentos.

Comment: Um exemplo legal que me ocorreu: *ímã* vs. *imã*.

Comment: Bah, eu nem sabia que existe a palavra *imã*.

Comment: É uma [autoridade religiosa do islamismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imame).

Comment: Relacionado: "[grafia e acentuação de órgão](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1248)" no FLiP.

Comment: @jbueno: Mas se o til pode fazer papel de acento quando coincidir de ser usado em silaba átona, para não ter que colocar dois símbolos gráficos, então não seria incorreto dizer que ele não é acento ? Mas sim algum tipo especial de acento, acento fraco, híbrido, volátil, ... não me veio nenhuma palavra adequada no momento para tentar definí-lo melhor.

Comment: Tens um exemplo? @Luciano

Comment: @jbueno: manha vs manhã, é um bom exemplo. Sem o til é uma paroxítona. Para o "nha" ser tônico precisa de acento, vamos inventar uma palavra: Manhá, e agora para nasalá-la troca-se o acento agudo por til: Manhã.

Answer (score 2):

Nós chamamos de diacrítico. Esse é o nome dado para o til (~) quando ele é usado para indicar a nasalidade de um fonema, vogais e sílabas nasais

Comment: Os acentos (agudo, grave, circunflexo) e o trema também são diacríticos.

Answer (score 0):

Permitam-me agregar algo às boas respostas dadas acima. Primeiramente, reforçar o fato de o til não ser um acento, mas, sim, um sinal indicativo de nasalização. Segundo, lembrar que as regras para a acentuação das paroxítonas é a seguinte: não serão acentuadas as paroxítonas terminadas em a(s), e(s) e o(s), em e ens. Portanto, 'orgão' deve ser acentuada, pois não tem essas terminações. No Brasil, ensina-se, no Ensino Médio, para facilitar a memorização -- o que acho que não ocorre --, que as paroxítonas terminadas em r,i(s),n,l,u(s),x, bem como ps, ã(s), on(s), um, uns e ão(s), são acentuadas, caso em que se encaixa 'órgão', por exemplo. Espero ter ajudado, caso não esteja equivocado.

Comment: É sempre bom incluir citações das fontes para regras gramaticais, se quiser pode ver como criar uma citação [neste post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4816). Um guia de formatação geral [está aqui no centro de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).