# Palavras com til são agudas em vez de graves. Porquê?

Tags: ortografia, gramática, acentuação

Por que é que em palavras como *li.**mão***, *a.ma.**nhã***, *co.me.**rão***, etc, a última sílaba é a sílaba tónica?

Este é um daqueles casos em que as palavras são agudas, mesmo sem acento? Como por exemplo, *a.**nel***, *co.zi.**nhar***, ou *cha.fa.**riz***?

---

#### Resposta curta (TL;DR): [link](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/853/201)

> O til ***não tem influência*** sobre qual a sílaba tónica... mas normalmente a sílaba tónica ***coincide*** com a que tem o til.

(Ênfase minha. Retirado da resposta aceitada.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As palavras com til não são necessariamente agudas.
Exemplos de palavras graves com til: órgão, orégão, sótão, órfão...
Citando a dúvida "[grafia e acentuação de órgão](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1248)" no FLiP (ênfase minha):

> É muito frequente, nas palavras que têm til, que o acento da palavra (que não tem de corresponder a um acento gráfico) coincida com o da sílaba que tem o sinal de nasalização (ex.: amamentação, calções, corrimão, manhã), **mas isso nem sempre se verifica**. Desta forma, podemos encontrar palavras que são acentuadas noutra sílaba que não aquela que tem o sinal de nasalização, quer com um acento gráfico (...) quer sem acento gráfico (...).

A maioria das palavras com til tem a sílaba tónica onde está o til.
Dentro das restantes, há tanto as que têm acento noutra sílaba (**ór**·fão) como as que não têm acento nenhum (ma·nhã·**zi**·nha).

---

Relacionado:

- Dúvida "[grafia e acentuação de órgão](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1248)" no FLiP;
- [Órgão leva dois acentos?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/442/porque-%C3%A9-que-%C3%B3rg%C3%A3o-leva-dois-acentos)

Comment: Devo concluir portanto que o til não tem influência sobre onde recai a sílaba tónica da palavra, certo?

Comment: Sim, @g4v3 , o til não tem influência sobre qual a sílaba tónica... mas normalmente a sílaba tónica coincide com a que tem o til.

Answer (score 2):

O til não é um acento gráfico. Apenas indica que a pronúncia é nasalada; ou seja que a palavra seria aguda mesmo sem o til, pois apenas acentos gráficos podem alterar a posição da sílaba tónica.

Comment: Quanto ao til, eu sei disso. Mas tanto quanto me lembro, na escola ensinaram-me que as palavras são graves (paroxítonas) quando não levam acento (agudo ou circunflexo), excepto se terminarem com certos sufixos, como -ar, -er, -ir, ..., -al, -el, -il, ..., -az, -ez, -iz, ...

Comment: Então em que ficamos?

Comment: someonewithpc o @user3397179 contradisse o que tu disseste...

Comment: @someonewithpc "a palavra seria aguda mesmo sem o til". Não sei, mas não parece que seja bem isso. Mas também não sei o suficiente para o provar. No entanto, no caso das palavras terminadas em *-a*, as palavras não seriam agudas: "amanha" (do verbo amanhar) e "amanhã" (no dia seguinte a hoje).

Answer (score 2):

O uso do "til" para palavras terminadas em "a" serve para diferenciar o som, que passa a produzir nasalidade.

Caso não tivesse o til, a palavra "manhã" (morning) teria a mesma pronúncia e seria indiferenciável de "manha" ("fake cry") e tem a pronúncia do "a" aberta.

Da mesma forma, palavras como "Mão" (hand), precisam do til, ou teriam sua pronuncia como "Mao" (como Mao-Tse-Tung).

O uso do til, portanto, faz-se necessário para diferenciar a pronúncia; sem ele o "ao" soaria como "au"; como em "cacau" (cocoa) ou "mau" (evil).

Comment: `teriam sua pronuncia como "Mao"`. Então é por isso que "ao" se lê da maneira como se lê! Tinha essa dúvida, a de como se deveriam ler palavras terminadas em "ão" se retirássemos o acento.

Comment: `"manha" ("fake cry")`. Desconheço tal significado da palavra. Para mim significa "capacidade ou jeito para enganar; engenho". A [Infopédia concorda com o meu uso](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/manha) da palavra, mas não mostra esse. Será que percebi mal? "fake cry" significa "choro fingido", certo?

Comment: Outra coisa, se a palavra "manhã" não levar til, deixa de ser grave e passa a ser aguda: ma.**nhã** → **ma**.nha

Comment: ... e mudando a sílaba tónica, a palavra é absolutamente diferenciável. Concordo com @user3397179 .

Comment: ***Reparei agora que troquei "grave" e "aguda".  Vou corrigir:*** Outra coisa, se a palavra "manhã" não levar til, deixa de ser *aguda* ("ma **nhã**") e passa a ser *grave* ("**ma**.nha").